# Split a number into its digits with Haskell

Tags: haskell

Given an arbitrary number, how can I process each digit of the number individually?

**Edit** 
I've added a basic example of the kind of thing `Foo` might do.

For example, in C# I might do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = 1234567890;
    string numberAsString = number.ToString();

    foreach(char x in numberAsString)
    {
        string y = x.ToString();
        int z = int.Parse(y);
        Foo(z);
    }
}

void Foo(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n*n);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838727/how-do-i-get-the-sums-of-the-digits-of-a-large-number-in-haskell

Comment: @FUZxxl because I want to work with each digit in turn as a number

Comment: Something like `showNumbers = show >=> return`?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Have you heard of [div and mod](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html)?

You'll probably want to reverse the list of numbers if you want to treat the most significant digit first. Converting the number into a string is an impaired way of doing things.

```
135 `div` 10 = 13
135 `mod` 10 = 5
```

Generalize into a function:

```
digs :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digs 0 = []
digs x = digs (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

Or in reverse:

```
digs :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digs 0 = []
digs x = x `mod` 10 : digs (x `div` 10)
```

This treats `0` as having no digits. A simple wrapper function can deal with that special case if you want to.

Note that this solution does not work for negative numbers (the input `x` must be integral, i.e. a whole number).

Comment: [quotRem](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Prelude.html#v%3AquotRem).

Comment: I've added an example to my code as I don't see how div and mod will help me walk over the digits of any arbitrary number. Could you expand on your thoughts please.

Comment: @Greg B this is a haskell source code that does the exact same thing your algorithm does, but using @supercooldave algorithm => http://pastie.org/1231091

Comment: so that digs 001 will be [0,0,1]

Comment: digs 001 = digs 1 = [1] because 001 = 1.

Comment: Just a reminder that this fails in the case of negative numbers.

Answer (score 29):

```
digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits = map (read . (:[])) . show
```

or you can return it into `[]`:

```
digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits = map (read . return) . show
```

or, with Data.Char.digitToInt:

```
digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits = map digitToInt . show
```

the same as Daniel's really, but point free and uses Int, because a digit shouldn't really exceed `maxBound :: Int`.

Comment: the `digitToInt` version is probably better anyway, and `:[]` was slightly more obvious to me. eh, I'll edit it in. I have no idea where pure is from, so.

Comment: reread this, this time recognizing `pure` and yes, that would be equivalent. (it is required to be equivalent.)

Comment: can you explain what the "period" does between read and return

Comment: function composition. `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

Comment: I like how this solution uses map versus pattern matching, such idiom!

Answer (score 15):

You could also just reuse [`digits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/digits) from Hackage.

Answer (score 15):

Textbook unfold

```
import qualified Data.List as L
digits = reverse . L.unfoldr (\x -> if x == 0 then Nothing else Just (mod x 10, div x 10))
```

Comment: Obviously this is the way to do. If you include `import Data.Bool.bool` then you can make it even more sexy like `unfoldr (\x -> bool Nothing (Just (rem x 10, div x 10)) (x > 0))`

Comment: Variant that works with negative numbers: `digits d = reverse . unfoldr (\x -> bool (Just $ swap $ divMod x 10) Nothing (x == 0)) $ abs d`. Needed imports: `Data.List (unfoldr)`, `Data.Tuple (swap)`, `Data.Bool (bool)`

Comment: Perfect solution, except that it is probably best to use divMod, if we are not sure whether the compiler will optimize the common work between div and mod all by itself.

Answer (score 14):

Using the same technique used in your post, you can do:

```
digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits n = map (\x -> read [x] :: Int) (show n)
```

See it in action:

```
Prelude> digits 123
[1,2,3]
```

Does that help?

Comment: digits 0123 should be [0,1,2,3]

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy No, `0123` isn't an Integer. If you were to use that literal in your code it would just be interpreted as the value `123` or `123.0` depending on the type. Try typing just `0123` in ghci.

Comment: Why does digits use both `Integer` and `Int` types as opposed to `Int -> [Int]` or `Integer -> [Integer]` ?

Comment: No real good reason. Using `Integer` for the input just means that the function accepts a "bigger number" than what `Int` does. And putting `Int` in the output... because it is a "smaller number". But, as you point out, pointless to do this.

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
digits = map (`mod` 10) . reverse . takeWhile (> 0) . iterate (`div` 10)
```

or for reverse order

```
rev_digits = map (`mod` 10) . takeWhile (> 0) . iterate (`div` 10)
```

The iterate part generates an infinite list dividing the argument in every step by 10, so 12345 becomes [12345,1234,123,12,1,0,0..]. The takeWhile part takes only the interesting non-null part of the list. Then we reverse (if we want to) and take the last digit of each number of the list.

I used point-free style here, so you can imagine an invisible argument n on both sides of the "equation". However, if you want to write it that way, you have to substitute the top level `.` by `$`:

```
digits n = map(`mod` 10) $ reverse $ takeWhile (> 0) $ iterate (`div`10) n
```

Answer (score 3):

Via list comprehension:

```
import Data.Char

digits :: Integer -> [Integer]
digits n = [toInteger (digitToInt x) | x <- show n]
```

output:

```
> digits 1234567890
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I was lazy to write my custom function so I googled it and tbh I was surprised that none of the answers on this website provided a really good solution – high performance and type safe. So here it is, maybe somebody would like to use it. Basically:

1. It is type safe - it returns a type checked non-empty list of Word8 digits (all the above solutions return a list of numbers, but it cannot happen that we get `[]` right?)
2. This one is performance optimized with tail call optimization, fast concatenation and no need to do any reversing of the final values.
3. It uses special assignment syntax which in connection to `-XStrict` allows Haskell to fully do strictness analysis and optimize the inner loop.

Enjoy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}

digits :: Integral a => a -> NonEmpty Word8
digits = go [] where
    go s x = loop (head :| s) tail where
        head = fromIntegral (x `mod` 10)
        tail = x `div` 10
    loop s@(r :| rs) = \case
        0 -> s
        x -> go (r : rs) x
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an improvement on an answer above. This avoids the extra 0 at the beginning ( Examples: [0,1,0] for 10, [0,1] for 1 ). Use pattern matching to handle cases where x < 10 differently:

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer] -- 12 -> [1,2], 0 -> [0], 10 -> [1,0]
toDigits x
    | x < 10 = [x]
    | otherwise = toDigits (div x 10) ++ [mod x 10]
```

I would have put this in a reply to that answer, but I don't have the needed reputation points :(

Answer (score 2):

[Applicative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor). [Pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree). [Origami](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/origami.pdf). Neat.

Enjoy:

```
import Data.List                                                                
import Data.Tuple                                                               
import Data.Bool                                                                
import Control.Applicative 

digits = unfoldr $ liftA2 (bool Nothing) (Just . swap . (`divMod` 10)) (> 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been following next steps(based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3989292/3727662)):

1. Convert the integer to a string.
2. Iterate over the string
   character-by-character.
3. Convert each character back to an integer,
   while appending it to the end of a list.

---

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits a = [(read([m])::Integer) | m<-show(a)]

main = print(toDigits(1234))
```

Answer (score 1):

For returning a list of [Integer]

```hs
import Data.Char
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n = map (\x -> toInteger (digitToInt x)) (show n)
```

Comment: Or in point free style it would be:
`toDigits = map (toInteger . digitToInt) . show`

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is great but fails in cases of negative numbers since `mod (-1) 10` evaluates to 9. If you would like this to handle negative numbers properly... which may not be the case the following code will allow for it.

```
digs :: Int -> [Int]
digs 0 = []
digs x
  | x < 0 = digs ((-1) * x)
  | x > 0 = digs (div x 10) ++ [mod x 10]
```

Comment: Could you refactor that with an `abs`?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct except that it will output an empty list when input is 0, however I believe the output should be `[0]` when input is zero.

And I don't think it deal with the case when the input is negative. Below is my implementation, which solves the above two problems.

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits n
 | n >=0 && n < 10 = [n]
 | n >= 10 = toDigits (n`div`10) ++ [n`mod`10]
 | otherwise = error "make sure your input is greater than 0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve upon the answer of Dave Clarke in this page. It boils down to using `div` and `mod` on a number and adding their results to a list, only this time it won't appear reversed, nor resort to `++` (which is slower concatenation).

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]

toDigits n
  | n <= 0    = []
  | otherwise = numToDigits (n `mod` 10) (n `div` 10) []
    where
      numToDigits a 0 l = (a:l)
      numToDigits a b l = numToDigits (b `mod` 10) (b `div` 10) (a:l)
```

---

This program was a solution to a problem in the CIS 194 course at UPenn that is available right [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html). You divide the number to find its result as an integer and the remainder as another. You pass them to a function whose third argument is an empty list. The remainder will be added to the list in case the result of division is 0. The function will be called again in case it's another number. The remainders will add in order until the end.

Note: this is for numbers, which means that zeros to the left won't count, and it will allow you to have their digits for further manipulation.

Answer (score -2):

```
digits = reverse . unfoldr go
  where go = uncurry (*>) . (&&&) (guard . (>0)) (Just . swap . (`quotRem` 10))
```

Comment: This answer would be much improved with an explanation

Comment: `quotRem` splits of the last digit basically and returns a tuple of the digit and the rest.

Answer (score -2):

I tried to keep using tail recursion

```
toDigits :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigits x = reverse $ toDigitsRev x

toDigitsRev :: Integer -> [Integer]
toDigitsRev x
    | x <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = x `rem` 10 : toDigitsRev (x `quot` 10)
```

Comment: This isn't tail recursion - there's a cons operation in the last branch other than the recursive call.

Comment: This isn't tail recursion - there's a cons operation in the last branch other than the recursive call.