# int -> [int] convert

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split a number into its digits with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell)

how can i convert integer to integer list 
Exmple: input: 1234 output:[1,2,3,4] any idee about this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Solution:
>
> ```
> digs 0 = []
> digs x = digs (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
> ```

Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell)

Comment: I thank you very much that was the code i needed. and thanks for the other replies. cheers

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like homework. Here's a general algorithm that you should be able to apply in Haskell:

1. Convert the integer to a string.
2. Iterate over the string character-by-character.
3. Convert each character back to an integer, while appending it to the end of a list.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for resisting the rep appeal and mentioning the *homework* word ;)

Answer (score 4):

Using integer arithmetic:

```
digits' 0 = []
digits' n = n `rem` 10 : digits (n `quot` 10)
digits n = reverse (digits' n)
```

Comment: Only problem is that `digits 0` gives you any empty list, but that's trivial to fix.  Also doesn't work for negative numbers, but its not clear what the right answer is in that case

Comment: @Chris: It does work for negative numbers. `digits (-42)` returns `[-4, -2]` which seems sensible to me.

Answer (score 3):

What about this quite simple solution?

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)

int2intList :: Integral i => i -> [Int]
int2intList s = map digitToInt $ show s

main = print $ int2intList 12351234999123123123
```

gives `[1,2,3,5,1,2,3,4,9,9,9,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`

This one is possible and a bit more universal, too:

```
int2intList :: (Read i, Integral i) => i -> [i]
int2intList s = map (read.(:[])) $ show s

main = print $ int2intList 12351234999123123123
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatative solution using [unfoldr](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-List.html#v%3aunfoldr):

```
import List
digits = reverse . unfoldr nextDigit
        where nextDigit 0 = Nothing
              nextDigit x = Just (r, q) where (q, r) = quotRem x 10
```

Answer (score 0):

jleedev:

I did something similar with divMod. I did not know that quotRem existed!

```
import Data.List ( unfoldr )

listify :: Integer -> [Integer]
listify = reverse . unfoldr f
   where
      f i = case divMod i 10 of
         (0, 0) -> Nothing
         (w, r) -> Just (r, w)
```