# int to integer list with three pairs

Tags: haskell

how can i do this integer value is converted to integerlist with three pairs from the and of the integer
input :  24889375
output : [375,889,24]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way you [do it with one digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989240/int-int-convert/3989293#3989293), except that you divide and mod by 1000 instead of 10.

Comment: @ifan: By removing the call to the `reverse` function.

Comment: digs 0 = []
digs x = digs (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
i take this one as a answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't list the language, so this will be pseudo code. Use the mod operator (% in The following)

First number = X % 1000;
Second Number = (X/1000)%1000;
Third Number = (X/1000000)%1000;

Note that these operations are all integer operations. The above only works if the / divide operator is an integer divide. If not, truncate it before calculating the modulo.

Comment: The language (Haskell) is in the tags.

Comment: Sorry still a newbie here and missed that. I'm not a Haskell guy, so my answer might not be applicable. Can delete if deemed not relevant...