# Haskell List of Int : [123] to [1,2,3]

Tags: list, haskell

**Problem**

i have list of int as [123,123] which i required to be as [1,2,3,1,2,3]

**Current Code**

i tried out the following code using recursion

```
fat::[Int]->[Int]
fat [] = []
fat (a,b,c:xs) = a : b : c : fat xs
```

**Conclusions**

i have no idea how to acess values as '1' , '2 , '3 in a list [123,123] separetly

Comment: For splitting a number into its digits, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell

Comment: For what?  Sounds like this question is suffering from the infamous [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Comment: I have no clue why someone downvoted this!? Please leave a comment if you do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I wrote it as suggested by @Ancide

**Implementation**

```
fat' :: [Int] -> [Int]
fat' l = map (read) [[z] | z <- [x | k <- (map (show) l), x <- k]]
```

**Explanation**:

*{- last result -}* stands for the result of the last code explained.

```
map (show) l
```

This takes every element inside *l* and converts it to *[String]*.

```
[x | k <- {- last result -}, x <- k]
```

While *k* goes through all elements inside the *last result*, *x* enumerates all character in each *k*. All those are added to a list. Now you have a *String*, respectively a *[Char]* with all digits next to each others.

```
[[z] | z <- {- last result -}]
```

This part takes each *Char* from the *String* and puts it into an empty *String*. Notice the *[z]* part! This make a list around *z*, which is (see above) the same as  *String*. Now you have a *list of String* with a *String* for each digit.

```
map (read) {- last result -}
```

This takes every item in the *last result* and converts it back to *Int* and joins them to *[Int]*. Now you have a list of type *[Int]* of the wanted result.

**Resumé**

Although this implementation is possible, it's neither fast, due to all the type conversions, nor readable.

Comment: NOTE: This is not how it's actually parsed by your Haskell Compiler. But taking lazy evaluation into this would be hardly understandable.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to use the `digs` function given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell/3963286#3963286) on each element of your list. It splits an `Int` into a list of digits (`[Int]`). Then you just need to concatenate the resulting lists. This 'map and concatenate results' requirement is a perfect job for [`concatMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:concatMap)

```
fat :: [Int] -> [Int]
fat = concatMap digs
```

This gives:

```
*Main> fat [123,123]
[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Which is what you want, if I understood correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
splitNum :: Int -> [Int]
splitNum n | n <= 9     = [n]
           | otherwise  = (splitNum (n `div` 10)) ++ [n `mod` 10]

fat :: [Int] -> [Int]
fat x = concatMap splitNum x
```

splitNum is used to convert an Int to a [Int] by splitting it into the division by ten reminders and appending the resulting Int to the splitted rest (recursion!)

Now, having a function that converts numbers into lists, go through input, apply splitNum to any Number in the inner list and concat all resulting lists (list comprehension!)

Comment: Beware: [01010] gets [1,0,1,0].

Comment: Ok, undownvoted.  Still would have preferred a little less "here's the code" and a little more guiding hand.

Comment: Of course it is: cse.chalmers.se/~hallgren/CactusExample/Haskell.bnf! After reducing this a little bit you get "integer = ['0'..'9']+ | "0"["oO"]Octal | "0"["xX"]Hexadecimal" For us, the first case of integer is interesting. 010101 fits "['0'..'9']+", therefore it is an integer

Answer (score 2):

As a new Haskell programmer I will give you my thoughts of this problem. Just because I think it's good to have many alternatives, especially from different people with different experience.

Here's my take on the problem:

- For each item in the list, convert that item to a char list using read.
- Send that char list into a function which converts each item of that list into an int, then return an list of ints.
- Concat that list of ints into the main list.

To clarify:

- [123, 234]
- 123 turns into ['1', '2', '3']
- ['1', '2', '3'] turns into [1, 2, 3]
- [1, 2, 3] gets concat in the main list
- the cycle repeats for 234.

The util function would look something like this:

```
import Char

charsToInts :: [Char] -> [Int]
charsToInts [] = []
charsToInts (x:xs) = digitToInt x : charsToInts xs
```

Coming from a imperative background that's how I would have solved it. Probably slower than just splitting the number mathematically, but I thought it would be interesting to show a alternative.

Comment: This would be really complex and complicated, because of read :: Read a => String -> a.

Comment: Mind explaining why or show me something to read about it? :) Would be perfect to learn more about it.

Comment: I don't think this fits in the comments section as there is no formatting.

EDIT: That does not mean I don't want to help you. But tell me how!

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Maybe I should read about the type system and try to understand it better to understand why this would be complicated? Or do you suggest I read about something else?

Comment: ISBN 9780521692694: A very good Haskell course book suitable for self-learning. Books about Haskell are very rare, but since Haskell is a hard to learn if you're on "conventional" languages and there are more popular functional languages like Scheme, only nerds (or people who know what they are doing) write about it.

Answer (score 2):

To pinpoint the problem bluntly, you have no idea how to access the digits separately because you do not understand Haskell types and pattern matching. Let me try to help dispel some of your misconceptions.

Let's look at your list:

```
[123, 123]
```

What is its *type*? It is clearly a list of ints, or `[Int]`. With lists, you can *pattern match* on the constructor `:`, known to lispers as "cons", or "list constructor". You put a single element on the left side of the `:`, and another list on the right side. The list on the right side can be the empty list `[]`, which basically indicates the end of the list. Haskell provides "syntactic sugar" to make lists easier to write, but `[123,456]` actually gets desugared into `123:(456:[])`. So when you pattern match `(x:y:z)`, you can now see that `x` will be assigned `123` and `y` will be assigned `456`. `z` will be the rest of the list after `x` and `y`; in this case only `[]` is left.

Now then, pattern matching with `:` works for *lists*. `Int`s are not lists, so you can't use `:` to pattern match on the digits of an `Int`. However, `String`s *are* lists, because `String` is the same as `[Char]`. So if you turn your `Int` into a `String` then you *can* pattern match on each character.

```
map show [123, 123]
```

`map` applies a function to all elements of a list. `show` can take an `Int` and turn it into a `String`. So we `map show` over the list of `Int`s to get a list of `String`s.

```
["123", "123"]
```

Now let's turn those `Strings` into lists of `Int`s. Since `String` is simply `[Char]`, we will again make use of `map`.

```
map digitToInt "123" -- this requires that you import Data.Char (digitToInt)
```

This will give us `[1,2,3]`; each `Char` in the list is turned into an `Int`. This is what we want to do to each `String` in our list `["123", "123"]`. We want to `map digitToInt` to each String. But we have a list of `String`s. So what do we do? We map it!

```
map (map digitToInt) ["123", "123"]
```

This will give us `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]`. Almost what we wanted. Now we just have to flatten the list of list of `Int`s (`[[Int]]`) into just a list of `Int` (`[Int]`). How can we do that? Stop...Hoogle time! [Hoogling](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5Ba%5D%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) [[a]] -> [a] we find the very first hit, `concat`, is exactly what we wanted.

Let's put it all together. First we do `map show` to get from `[Int]` to `[String]`. Then we do `map (map digitToInt)` to get from `[String]` to `[[Int]]`. Then we do `concat` to get from `[[Int]]` to `[Int]`. Then we'll just `print` it out!

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
main = print $ concat $ map (map digitToInt) $ map show $ [123, 123]
```

Now let's pull most of that out into a function `fat`

```
import Data.Char (digitToInt)
main = print $ fat [123, 123]
fat :: [Int] -> [Int]
fat xs = concat $ map (map digitToInt) $ map show $ xs
```

From here you could make it prettier in a few different ways. `concat $ map` is the same as `concatMap`, and since we map both `(map digitToInt)` and `show` in sequence, we can merge those. Also making it pointfree, we can end up with quite a terse definition:

```
fat = concatMap (map digitToInt . show)
```

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with the list monad I came up with this. Pretty much the same @Ankur's solution, except using the list monad:

```
fat :: [Int] -> [Int]
fat is = is >>= show >>= return . digitToInt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had two numbers, `a` and `b` then you could turn them into a single number by doing 10*a + b.  The same principles apply for three.

It sounds like one way of doing this would be to [splitEvery](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/split/0.1.1/doc/html/Data-List-Split.html) into lumps of three and then `map` a function to turn a list of three into a single number.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to convert Integer to string... which is obviously Show function
Another function to convert a Char to Integer which is "digitToInt" in module Char

And here we go :

```
fat::[Int]->[Int]
fat [] = []
fat ls = concat $ map (map digitToInt) (map show ls)
```

Please let me know if it works :)