# Haskell Integer Odd Digits Checker

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

I seem to be stuck on a question and have no idea how to approach it or what Im doing wrong with my current code.

I have to write a function called oddDigits which takes a single integer argument and returns a boolean result. It should return True if and only if the argument is a positive integer with an odd number of digits. If the argument is zero or negative, the function should stop with an error message.

Also, cant convert the argument into a string. Have to use recursion. 
I have a feeling each digit could be stored in a list recursively and then the length of the list could determine the answer.

So far, I have this:

```
oddDigits :: Integer -> Bool 

lst = [] 

oddDigits x 
    | (x < 0) || (x == 0) = error 
    | x `mod` 10 ++ lst ++ oddDigits(x `div` 10) 
    | length(lst) `mod` 2 /= 0 = True
    | otherwise = False
```

Sorry if the code looks horrible. I am new to Haskell and still learning. What exactly am I doing wrong and how could I correct it?

Answer (score 4):

First off, this seems a pretty weird thing to check. Perhaps what you're doing wrong is to ever consider this problem...

[image: XKCD Wikipedia printer]

But if you persist you want to know the property of *an integer having an odd number of digits*... oh well. There's a lot that could be improved. For starters, `(x < 0) || (x == 0)` doesn't need the parentheses – `<` and `==` (infix 4) bind more tightly than `||`. If you're not sure about this, you can always ask GHCi:

```
Prelude> :i ==
class Eq a where
  (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
infix 4 ==
Prelude> :i ||
(||) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
infixr 2 ||
```

But here you don't need `||` anyway because there's a dedicated operator for less-than-or-equal. Hence you can just write

```
oddDigits x 
  | x <= 0  = error "bla bla"
  | ...
```

Then, [you *can*](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Integer+-%3E+String) “convert” the number to a string. Converting to string is generally a really frowned-upon thing to do because it throws all structure, typechecking etc. out of the window; however “number of digits” basically *is* a property of a string (the decimal expansion), rather than a number itself, so this is not entirely unsensible for this specific task. This would work:

```
oddDigits x 
 | x <= 0                      = error "blearg"
 | length (show x)`mod`2 /= 0  = True
 | otherwise                   = False
```

however it's a bit redundancy department redundant. You're checking if something is `True`, then give `True` as the result... why not just put it in one clause:

```
oddDigits x 
 | x <= 0     = error "blearg"
 | otherwise  = length (show x)`mod`2 /= 0
```

That's perhaps in fact the best implementation.

For any *proper*, sensible task, I would not recommend going the string route. Recursion is better. Here's what it could look like:

```
oddDigits 1 = True
oddDigits x 
 | x <= 0     = error "blearg"
 | otherwise  = not . oddDigits $ x`div`10
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your general approach of converting to a list of digits, then finding the length of the list.  Really where you went wrong is trying to cram everything into one function.  As you found out first hand, it makes it very difficult to debug.  Functional programming works best with *very* small functions.

If you separate out the responsibility of converting an integer to a list of digits, using a `digs` function like the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3963286/389146), the rest of your algorithm simplifies to:

```
oddDigits x | x <= 0 = error
oddDigits x = odd . length $ digs x
```

Answer (score 0):

leftaroundabout's eventual answer is very nice, however it fails for numbers like 2,3 and 23. Here's a fix.

```
oddDigits x 
  | x <= 0     = error "blearg"
  | x < 10     = True
  | otherwise  = not . oddDigits $ x`div`10
```

Its much more elegant than my initial answer, below. I'm including it to introduce a common functional paradigm, a worker/wrapper transformation of the problem. Here the wrapper gives the interface and passes off the work to another function. Notice that the negativity check only needs to be done once now.

```
oddDigits :: Integer -> Bool
oddDigits x
   | x <= 0 = False
   | otherwise = oddDigits' True x

oddDigits' :: Bool -> Integer -> Bool
oddDigits' t x
   | x < 10 = t
   | otherwise = oddDigits' (not t) $ x `div` 10
```

`oddDigits'` carries a piece of internal data with it, the initial Bool. My first first thought was to have that Bool be a digit accumulator, counting the number of digits. In that case, an "unwrapper" needs to be supplied, in this case the standard "odd" function:

```
oddDigits x
   | x <= 0 = False
   | otherwise = odd . oddDigits'' 1  $  x
```

where `oddDigits'' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer`.