# Haskell recursion slow, what's the pitfall?

Tags: haskell, optimization

I'm very much a beginner in Haskell

```
data Recipes = Recipes Int Int Int [Int] deriving(Show) 

addRecipes :: Recipes -> Recipes
addRecipes (Recipes t e1 e2 list) = 
    let (e1c, e2c) = (list !! e1, list !! e2)
        newVal = e1c + e2c
        newList = list ++ (digits $ newVal)
        e1n = calcNewPos e1 e1c newList
        e2n = calcNewPos e2 e2c newList
    in Recipes t e1n e2n newList

calcNewPos :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int    
calcNewPos i i2 list = (i + i2 + 1) `mod` (length list)

-- Borrowed:
-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits = map (read . (:[])) . show
```

The above piece of code is part of a recursion which I omitted. The `addRecipes` is called again and again in a recursive call. This is a solution to an advent of code problem (AoC 2018 day 14). The code produces the correct result but is cripplingly slow.

I'm just trying to learn where the problem lies, what is horribly inefficient in the code above?

I've tried optimizing away the `++`-operator and replace it with a `:` and combining things with the digits call. I know the `++` is slower than the `:` but is that really it? (Remember, i'm learning Haskell so I want to fix this code if possible and know why I can't write it like this)

Edit: The list in Recipes grows and becomes large

Comment: If you need a lot of random access, like `list !! n`, or appending `list ++ something`, the basic list is not an appropriate data structure. It's hard to suggest what to use, without understanding the general picture. Perhaps an array suffices, or `Seq` / `Vector` are needed. Maybe you can do without random access, and then lists are fine.

Comment: Hmm ok, https://adventofcode.com/2018/day/14 there is the puzzle if interested... But that might be helpful, I will investigate the `!!`, maybe I can remove it somehow

Comment: After I finished this problem I realised that all the work is done at the end of the sequence, and so you could probably get away with using just a list if you keep it in reverse order.  (And keep track of the length.)  But it would be easy to get wrong and using `Seq` will be a lot simpler.

Comment: Just to expand on @DavidFletcher's comment, `Seq` refers to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html

Comment: It worked with Seq! 1h -> 2 sec. Thanks, I do however get : "getMBlocks: VirtualAlloc MEM_COMMIT failed: The paging file is too small for this operation to complete."  on my recursion endCondition: `Seq.take 6 (Seq.reverse seq) == part2Input = Seq.length seq - 5`. I'll self answer, but if you have pointers on that last hurdle I'll take em! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice posted in the comments; Do not use a the list data structure when you make a lot of random accesses. So I replaced the list with with Sequence http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq

data Recipes = Recipes Int Int Int (Seq.Seq Int) deriving(Show) 

addRecipes :: Recipes -> Recipes
addRecipes (Recipes t e1 e2 seq) = 
let (e1c, e2c) = (Seq.index seq e1, Seq.index seq e2)
    newVal = e1c + e2c
    newSeq = (Seq.><) seq (Seq.fromList (digits newVal))
    e1n = calcNewPos e1 e1c newSeq
    e2n = calcNewPos e2 e2c newSeq
in Recipes t e1n e2n newSeq

calcNewPos :: Int -> Int -> (Seq.Seq Int) -> Int    
calcNewPos i i2 seq = (i + i2 + 1) `mod` (Seq.length seq)
```

It worked and the run time is now reasonable (from 1 hour to seconds). Thanks commenters!

Comment: You could write `(Seq.><) seq (Seq.fromList (digits newVal))` as `seq Seq.>< Seq.fromList (digits newVal)`.