# Haskell recursion pitfall, what's is slowing it down?

Tags: haskell

I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53802071/haskell-recursion-slow-whats-the-pitfall) two years ago. And I'm in the same position again! for [this year's Advent of Code, day 10](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/10) puzzle.

The recursive core of the algorithm looks like:

> ```
> recurse :: Seq.Seq Int -> Int
> recurse xs = Seq.foldlWithIndex checkIt 0 $ xs
>     where checkIt acc i _
>             | i == 0 = acc
>             | i + 1 == length xs = acc
>             | Seq.index xs (i+1) - Seq.index xs (i-1) < 3 = acc + 1 + (recurse $ Seq.deleteAt i xs)
>             | otherwise = acc
> ```

I've experimented with `foldl` and `foldr` with no difference. Also I had an entirely different version which looked something like (and its counterpart without [Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) and a list instead):

> ```
> withNeighbour :: Seq.Seq a -> Seq.Seq (a,a,a)
> withNeighbour xs = Seq.zip3 withoutLastElement (Seq.drop 1 withoutLastElement) (Seq.drop 2 xs)
>      where withoutLastElement = (Seq.deleteAt (length xs - 1) xs)
>
> recurse :: Seq.Seq Int -> Int
> recurse xs = foldr checkIt 0 $ withNeighbour xs
>     where checkIt (x,y,z) acc = if z - x < 3 then acc + 1 + (recurse $ Seq.deleteAt (head $ Seq.findIndicesL (find y) xs) xs) else acc
>           find x y = x == y
> ```

Is something killing the performance of the implementation of this algorithm or is it the algorithm itself which is bad? It can't even handle the large test-set in the assignment. Is it the triple `O(log(min(i,n−i)))` in its heart, if so can it be done away with?

Comment: is `xs` the direct puzzle input mapped into a seq of ints? Also yes, raw recursion on this is not a very good idea. You *will* require memoization at the very least to make it work at a *reasonable* time. Though, even then, it's not very ideal. Remember that there are *trillions* of possible arrangements in your actual puzzle input

Comment: (xs is massaged input from the puzzle) Hmm yeah I discussed a more mathsy solution with a friend. But then he said his recurse solution worked, and i didn't imagine him doing memoization... but maybe he did. Should maybe try that then. Like just add a Map with different sequences as keys as first argument to the 'recurse', does that sound stupid?

Comment: I'd suggest you to notice the properties of the combinations. If you haven't already sorted the list, do that first. Then try to find the *groups* that can have multiple arrangements. You can still make recursive solutions - this particular one will simply blow out of proportion extremely fast

Comment: I've literally only just solved this problem (not in Haskell this year as I try to experiment with different languages in AoC) - and I only did so by making certain observations about the data that massively simplified it (and which needn't have been true, but in fact were). Still not sure if I cheated or if we were *supposed* to notice certain things about the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my own solution below, with a discussion of how I got there. This is probably not the most Haskell-y solution, and I'd be very interested to see one that doesn't have to dip into the messy business of the `ST` monad to get there.

The problem, as you've correctly pointed out, is the amount of recursion.

We can eliminate this to a certain extent by sorting the list first (note that `Data.Sequence` helpfully provides a `sort` function, saving us the minimal trouble of writing it ourselves). By sorting the list, we know that all of the "compatible" joltages to a given adapter are either one, two, or three places before it in the list. Now, rather than recursing on, theoretically, all possible sublists (`2^31` possibilities, in your sample input from the problem), we only really need to recurse on all initial subsequences (`31` possibilities).

Unfortunately, even if we make that correction, we're still calling a ton of things redundantly. There may only be 31 calls going around, but the same 31 calls are getting made a *lot* more than 31 times. Also, we know that a given adapter only depends on the adapters of lower joltage than itself (we're never going to go up to a higher joltage and then back down), so we have a bunch of recursive calls in an order that we understand. We can solve this problem using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Unfortunately (again), this is where Haskell gets a bit awkward. Dynamic programming is usually, and most efficiently, backed with a mutable array. Haskell's built-in mutable array type leaves a lot to be desired, but we'll roll with it here.

**Spoiler for Advent of Code 2020 Day 10:**

> ```
>  import Data.Sequence(Seq(..), (<|), (|>))
>  import qualified Data.Sequence as Seq
>  import Data.Array.ST
>  import Data.Array.MArray
>  import Control.Monad
>  import Control.Monad.ST
>
>  -- The "large" test set listed in the assignment.
>  example :: Seq Integer
>  example = Seq.fromList [28, 33, 18, 42, 31, 14, 46, 20, 48, 47, 24, 23, 49, 45, 19, 38, 39, 11, 1, 32, 25, 35, 8, 17, 7, 9, 4, 2, 34, 10, 3]
>
>  -- We're going to call this once for each position in the sequence.
>  -- This is what would be your recursive step in the original
>  -- algorithm.
>  writePos :: Seq Integer -> STArray s Int Integer -> Int -> ST s ()
>  writePos s arr i = do
>    -- We need to look three steps behind, as the "current" adapter can
>    -- hook up to anything up to three positions before it. Go ahead and
>    -- omit any positions which are out of bounds.
>    let predecessors = [j | j <- [1, 2, 3], i - j >= 0]
>    v <- readArray arr i
>    -- For each possible predecessor...
>    forM_ predecessors $ \j ->
>      -- If the joltages are compatible...
>      when (Seq.index s i - Seq.index s (i - j) <= 3) $ do
>        -- Then we can plug this adapter into the current one. Add any
>        -- possible ways to get to the current one to the predecessor.
>        u <- readArray arr (i - j)
>        writeArray arr (i - j) (u + v)
>
>  countTotal :: Seq Integer -> Integer
>  countTotal s = runST $ do
>    -- Sort the list so we know what order to go in. Tack a 0 at the
>    -- beginning and a (max + 3) at the end for our starting conditions.
>    let s' = (0 <| Seq.sort s) |> (3 + maximum s)
>    -- Make an array to store our intermediates.
>    arr <- newArray (0, Seq.length s' - 1) 0
>    -- To start with, put a 1 at the end.
>    writeArray arr (Seq.length s' - 1) 1
>    -- For each position (starting at the end) make a note of which
>    -- adapters the given adapter can plug into, keeping score along the
>    -- way.
>    mapM_ (writePos s' arr) [Seq.length s' - 1,Seq.length s' - 2..0]
>    -- Return the number of ways we can get to our 0-joltage plug.
>    readArray arr 0
>
>  -- Use as `countTotal example`
> ```

Like I said, not the most Haskell-y solution, but there's no observable side effects on the function at least (all mutation happens locally). This can probably be done with some clever folds and an immutable list argument, but *c'est la vie*.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say I came up with a pretty functional/haskell-y solution. Here's my thought process-

Let's walk through the small input-

```
16
10
15
5
1
11
7
19
6
12
4
```

First order of business is sorting, do that and you get-

```hs
[1,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,19]
```

Now, look at the re-arrangements demonstrated on the aoc page. Notice how the re-arrangements are only present in `[4, 5, 6, 7]` and `[10, 11, 12]`?

Every contiguous group, where the elements are only 1 rating apart, with a length of *at least* 3 - will exhibit the ability to be re-arranged. Notice that if the sorted list was

```hs
[1,4,5,8,11,12,15,16,19]
```

The only re-arrangements would exist in `[10, 11, 12]` - `[4, 5]` doesn't have any re-arrangements. It's only a list of length 2, the only adapter to go from 4 *is* 5.

So, grouping the elements and counting their combinations seems plausible. Next is a function to calculate the possible combinations of a list, given its length

> ```
>  adapCombs :: Int -> Int
>  adapCombs 0 = 0
>  adapCombs 1 = 1
>  adapCombs 2 = 1
>  adapCombs n = adapCombs (n - 1) + adapCombs (n - 2) + adapCombs (n - 3)
> ```

Pretty simple right? You pass it the length, it gives you all the possible combinations. Do note that the `n=0`is a dummy case. It'll never happen with the given input.

For a list of length 1 or 2 (`[4]` and `[4, 5]`) - you can only have **one** arrangement, the sorted one! For a list of length `n`, you can have `adapCombs (n - 1) + adapCombs (n - 2) + adapCombs (n - 3)` number of arrangements

So for `n=3`, you can have 2 arrangements. `[4, 5, 6]` -> `[4, 5, 6]` and `[4, 6]`
For `n=4`, you can have 4 arrangements.
For `n=5`, you can have 7 arrangements.

Conveniently, the max length of a subgroup (in my puzzle input and many others) was 5. Yes, just 5! You can literally calculate all these combinations *by hand* and hardcode them - for optimal performance, yes?

That's not super neat though, who knows what your puzzle input will look like. So we'll memoize it instead-

> ```
>  adapCombs :: Int -> Int
>  adapCombs = (map go [0..] !!)
>   where
>     go 0 = 0
>     go 1 = 1
>     go 2 = 1
>     go n = adapCombs (n - 1) + adapCombs (n - 2) + adapCombs (n - 3)
> ```

That should do.

Now, all you have to do, is subgroup the sorted list, apply this function over each group and `product`

> ```
>  -- Calculate the final combination by multiplying all the combinations
>  product
>  -- Calculate number of combinations of each sublist
>  . map (adapCombs . length)
>  {- Group all numbers that are 1 rating apart from each other
>  Turns [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 11, 15, 16, 19] to [[19],[16,15],[11],[9,8],[3,2,1,0]] >! -}
>  . foldl (\acc@(front:rest) x ->
>     if x - head front == 1
>     then (x:front):rest
>     else [x]:acc
>  )
>  -- Start with 0
>  [[0]]
> ```

Apply this over your sorted list and you're done. That `foldl` there is the grouping function, it's pretty straight forward. `groupBy` from `Data.List` wouldn't work since it compares to the first element of a subgroup, rather than each consecutive pair.

Now, this isn't *actually* the best solution. You don't need to subgroup at all! You can do this in one traversal, by keeping a list of 3 elements that keeps track of the previous combinations (the principle is still similar). But this just works better as a functional solution rather than an iterative one.

#### Edit: To explain my thought process behind coming up with `adapCombs`

I came up with `adapCombs` by writing down the combinations for different length adapter groups. First thing to notice is that when `n=1` or `n=2` (i.e `[4]` or `[4, 5]`) - there's **only one** arrangement. This is self-explanatory.

Next I tried drafting up the combs for `n=3`, `[4, 5, 6]`.

4 can either go to 5, or 6

- If it goes to 5 (`4->5`), then `5` can only go to `6`, so `4->5->6` is an arrangement
- If it goes to 6 (`4->6)`, there's nothing else to go to anymore, this is the full arrangement

So for `n=3`, re-arrangements is 2.

I didn't notice a pattern just yet, but I assure you, there's a **very** noticable pattern here. I'll come back to it later.

Now, for `n=4` - `[4, 5, 6, 7]`

Right off the bat, 4 can go to 3 choices - 5, 6, and 7. It's apparent that this is the maximum choices you can possibly have from one adapter - 3. Since the gap size of the puzzle (maximum deviation to construct the chain) is also 3.

Here's where the recursive pattern became apparent

- If 4 goes to 5, 5 can go to either 6, or 7. i.e 5 has the same number of arrangements as `n=3` previously - 2. And that makes perfect sense, after all the path when you choose 5 is `[5, 6, 7]` - a group of length 3! So `4->5` can have 2 arrangements, `4->5->6->7` and `4->5->7`.
- If 4 goes to 6, now we're dealing with `[6, 7]` - a group of length 2. Remember how many arrangements a group of length 2 can have? just 1! So `4->6->7` is the only arrangement here
- If 4 goes to 7, now we're dealing with `[7]` - a group of length 1. Once again, the re-arrangements is just 1 - `4->7`

So the total arrangements is 2 + 1 + 1 = 4. Which is correct!

I then went on to hand-verify this pattern with `n=5` - `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

We'll follow the same exact pattern. 4 can go to, at max, 3 choices - 5, 6, and 7

- If 4 goes to 5, we're dealing with `[5, 6, 7, 8]` - recall a group of length 4 will have 4 arrangements (previous example). So the number of arrangements in this path is 4
- If 4 goes to 6, we're dealing with `[6, 7, 8]` - arrangements for `n=3` is 2
- If 4 goes to 7, we're dealing with `[7, 8]` - arrangements for `n=2` is 1

So the total arrangements is 4 + 2 + 1 = 7 for `n=5`. Which is correct!

So, for each `n>=3`, you just need to know *at max* the previous 3 lengths' arrangements.

Going back to `n=3` example, `4` is *actually going to 3 choices* - 5, 6 and Nothing! We can represent nothing as `[]`, a group of length 0. This is why `adapCombs 0 = 0`. Feel free to bake in `n=3` as a default case though, then you can start from `n>=4` and won't need the `adapCombs 0` filler.

So the final formula, would be `f n = f (n - 1) + f (n - 2) + f (n - 3)` for all `n >= 3`, given `f 0 = 0`, `f 1 = 1`, and `f 2 = 2`

Comment: This was essentially what I did, after realising that, at least for my input, all the gaps were either 1 or 3 (never 2), and that none of the sequences of consecutive numbers were longer than 5. So I did indeed just hard-code the number of arrangements of those. (I did think about a general recursive solution for that part but, embarrassingly, I couldn't figure it out! Would be interested to hear where your recursive formula came from.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond sure, I explained how I came with `adapCombs` in the edit

Comment: I see, thanks. Obvious once it's been explained! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that there is an exponential explosion in the recursion.  Each `recurse xs` call invokes multiple `recurse` calls on subsequences of `xs` with one element deleted, one recursive call for each element between two elements less than 3 units apart.  Each of those recursive calls, similarly, invoke multiple `recurse` calls in the same manner.

In a worst case, a list of consecutive integers `[1..100]` will invoke 98 recursive calls (since you recurse on `2` through `99`), each of which will invoked 97 recursive calls, etc.

This is similar to what happens with a naive Fibonacci implementation:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

where, for sufficiently large `n`, the call `fib n` invokes two recursive calls, each of which invoke two recursive call and so on.

The usual solution is to memoize.  This is easy for `fib`, and you can use something like the `memoize` library:

```
import Data.Function.Memoize

fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)

fib' :: Int -> Int
fib' = memoize fib
```

or use Haskell's "magical memoization" with lazy and/or recursive data structures:

```
fibs :: [Int]
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

Unfortunately, memoizing your `recurse` doesn't help much because it's parameterized on an exponential number of subsequences.  The memoization helps avoid recalculating answers for the same subsequence when you arrive at it by deleting the same set of elements in a different order, but there are still far too many subsequences to evaluate.

Instead, you need to memoize on something that's, say, linear in the size of the problem.  It turns out that this is relatively easy.

**SPOILERS FOLLOW...**

Note that in a sorted sequence (including the starting point of 0) like:

```
[0,2,3,5,6,7]
```

once you've reached a certain adapter, say 3,

> there are a fixed number of valid sequences of larger adapters that end with the final adapter 7, namely the three sequences:  [5,6,7], [5,7], and [6,7].  It doesn't matter how you *got* to adapter 3 -- once you're there, there are always three ways to proceed.  So, all we need to do is write a recursion that, given the current adapter, gives the number of sequences of larger adapters.

This is fairly easily done in non-memoized form:

> ```
> -- get number of routes through higher adapters
> routes :: Int -> Int
> -- there's one route from the last adapter
> routes j | j == last js = 1
> -- read the following comments in reverse order:
> routes j =
>     sum . map routes   -- add up the routes from those adapters
>   . takeWhile (<=j+3)  -- keep those within jumping distance
>   . dropWhile (<=j)    -- get larger adapters
>   $ js
> ```

This is fast enough, as is, for both "small" examples in the AoC site.  Specifically:

> ```
>     import Data.List
>
>     solve :: [Int] -> Int
>     solve inp = routes 0
>       where js = 0 : sort inp
>             routes :: Int -> Int
>             routes j | j == last js = 1
>             routes j =
>                 sum . map routes
>               . takeWhile (<=j+3)
>               . dropWhile (<=j)
>               $ js
>
>     main = do
>       print $ solve [16,10,15,5,1,11,7,19,6,12,4]
>       print $ solve [28,33,18,42,31,14,46,20,48,47,24,23,49,45,19,38,39,11,1,32,25,35,8,17,7,9,4,2,34,10,3]
> ```

It also works correctly on inputs where the adapters are spaced two apart, unlike some of the other answers posted here:

```
> solve [1,3,4]
3   -- shouldn't be 1
```

If it's memoized, it works on the large puzzle input:

> ```
>     import Data.List
>     import Data.Function.Memoize
>
>     solve :: [Int] -> Int
>     solve inp = routes 0
>       where js = 0 : sort inp
>             routes :: Int -> Int
>             routes j | j == last js = 1
>             routes j =
>                 sum . map routes'   -- use memoized version
>               . takeWhile (<=j+3)
>               . dropWhile (<=j)
>               $ js
>             routes' = memoize routes
>
>     main = do
>       print $ solve [16,10,15,5,1,11,7,19,6,12,4]
>       print $ solve [28,33,18,42,31,14,46,20,48,47,24,23,49,45,19,38,39,11,1,32,25,35,8,17,7,9,4,2,34,10,3]
>       print . solve . map read . lines =<< readFile "day10.in"
> ```

You can also use Haskell's implicit memoization.  My original solution was:

> ```
>     routes :: (Num a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int
>     routes js = snd . head $ jRoutes
>       where jRoutes = zip (0 : sort js) (map routes1 (tails jRoutes))
>             routes1 [(j,)] = 1
>             routes1 ((j,):rest) = sum . map snd . takeWhile ((<= j + 3) . fst) $ rest
> ```

The data structure here is a little more complicated to avoid searching the whole list for the adapter of interest every time.