# Circular prime numbers

Tags: haskell, integer, primes

I am trying to convert the following function which test the number if it's prime to another one that test if the integer is a circular prime.
eg. 1193 is a circular prime, since 1931, 9311 and 3119 all are also prime.
So i need to rotate the digits of the integer and test if the number is prime or not. any ideas? 
note: I am new to Haskell Programming

```
isPrime ::  Integer -> Bool

isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n 
 | (length [x | x <- [2 .. n-1],  n  `mod` x == 0]) > 0 = False
 | otherwise = True 


isCircPrime ::  Integer -> Bool
```

Comment: What did you try to rotate the numbers?

Comment: I don't know how to rotate the number in a way that convert a number like 1193 to 
1931,9311,3119

Comment: can you make a fair attempt to implement that and specify what is not working with that attempt? Hint: use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell

Answer (score 2):

You can improve the efficiency and elegance of your `isPrime` function easily by implementing it as:

```
isPrime ::  Integral i => i -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime n = all ((/=) 0 . mod n) (takeWhile (\x -> x*x <= n) [2..])
```

In order to rotate numbers, we can make use of two helper functions here: one to convert a number to a list of digits, and one to convert a list of digits to a number, we do this in reverse, since that is more convenient to implement, but will not matter:

```
num2dig :: Integral i => i -> [i]
num2dig n | n < 10 = [n]
          | otherwise = r : num2dig q
    where (q, r) = quotRem n 10


dig2num :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
dig2num = foldr ((. (10 *)) . (+)) 0
```

Now we can make a simple function to generate, for a list of items, all rotations:

```
import Control.Applicative(liftA2)
import Data.List(inits, tails)

rots :: [a] -> [[a]]
rots = drop 1 . liftA2 (zipWith (++)) tails inits
```

So we can use this to construct all rotated numbers:

```
rotnum :: Integral i => i -> [i]
rotnum = map dig2num . rots . num2dig
```

For example for `1425`, the rotated numbers are:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative Data.List> rotnum 1425
[5142,2514,4251,1425]
```

I leave using `isPrime` on these numbers as an exercise.

Comment: could you provide more simple approach because there is a lot here that I don't understand. If you could suggest a solution using the functions in the duplicated question I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Referencing your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226986/circular-prime-using-simple-haskell-functions), you can achieve what you want by adding a single new function:

```
check :: Integer -> Bool
check n = and [isPrime (stringToInt cs) | cs <- circle (intToString n)]
```

This is to add an easier to understand solution from where you already were in your specific code, as I can see you were asking for that specifically. Usage:

```
*Main> check 1931
True

*Main> check 1019
False
```

Mind you, I have made some type-changes. I assume you want each function to be type-specific, due to their names. Full code, taken from your example:

```
circle :: String -> [String]
circle xs = take (length xs) (iterate (\(y:ys) -> ys ++ [y]) xs)

stringToInt :: String -> Integer
stringToInt x = read (x) :: Integer

intToString :: Integer -> String
intToString x = show x

isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime 1 = False
isPrime 2 = True
isPrime n
    | (length [x | x <- [2 .. n-1], n `mod` x == 0]) > 0 = False
    | otherwise = True

check :: Integer -> Bool
check n = and [isPrime (stringToInt cs) | cs <- circle (intToString n)]
```