# Why does this function used by map need to return a (singleton) list instead of an element?

Tags: haskell

Total beginner as you might have guessed. I've gone through "Learn you a Haskell" but I still struggle with even the basics.

I'm looking at this thread
[Split a number into its digits with Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963269/split-a-number-into-its-digits-with-haskell)
and things start to make sense with this function

```
digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits n = map (\x -> read [x] :: Int) (show n)
```

asked by Daniel.

I understand that show returns my input number as a String, or list of Chars, which then I can modify element by element using map. So, each "x", as a Char, is picked by the anonymous function and read as an Integer and the new list is composed by map, containing all the read integers. Shouldn't then `read [x]` be `read x`? Why does every read Char in the list need to be returned as it's own singleton list? It seems to me that this way calling `digits 123` should return `[[1],[2],[3]]`, since map will compose everything into a new list anyway and not `[1,2,3]` as it correctly does. But why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`read :: Read a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) works on a `String`, not on a `Char` and here `x` is a `Char`.

Indeed, `show n` constructs a `String`, which is a list of `Char`s, since `type String = [Char]`. If we perform a mapping over the list of `Char`s, then `x` is a `Char` in the mapping function. We wrap it in a singleton list to construct a `String` with one `Char`acter, and then use `read` to read that string as an `Int`.

We can however make use of [**`digitToInt :: Char -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) which is probably more efficient and elegant:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

digits :: Integer -> [Int]
digits = map digitToInt . show
```

Comment: Huh, I hadn’t known about `digitToInt` before. Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 5):

Let’s have a look at the type of `read`:

```
Prelude> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

That is, for any type `a` which is an instance of `Read`, the `read` function can be used to convert a `String` to a member of that type. Note here that the argument of `read` is a `String` — not a `Char`! Thus, in order to convert a `Char` to some other type using `read`, you first need to convert the `Char` to a `String`. And how do you do that? Well, remember that a `String` is just a list of `Char`s: `type String = [Char]`. Thus, you convert a `Char` to a `String` by wrapping it in a list — which is exactly what your code is doing. You can confirm this is necessary yourself in GHCi:

```
Prelude> read '1' :: Int

<interactive>:10:6: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Char
    * In the first argument of `read', namely '1'
      In the expression: read '1' :: Int
      In an equation for `it': it = read '1' :: Int
Prelude> read "1" :: Int
1
Prelude> read ['1'] :: Int
1
Prelude> :t ['1']
['1'] :: [Char]
Prelude> :t "1"
"1" :: [Char]
Prelude> :t '1'
'1' :: Char
```

(I should note that the rest of your summary of the code is totally correct, by the way.)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was a stupid question...
The singleton list is there because read requires it as input, a String, not a single Char, and the result is indeed a single Int. Baby steps...